# UIAlertView shows up several times after Home Button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uialertview

Iam calling this Code in my ViewController if some Settings are not set or are (by the length) zero:

```
UIAlertView *infoView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Achtung", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"Wrong Settings",nil)delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [infoView show];
    [infoView release];
```

The Alertview shows up and if I press the Home Button and start the App again it shows the Alert zwice, after that if i press the Home Button again and start the App the Alert shows up 4 times.....

Why the hell is it like this?

I tried to define a new function for it and tried many other workarounds but nothing worked out for me.

Somebody any Suggestions?

Comment: U might be calling alert View 4 times, please check out your code properly.

Comment: Your UIAlertView is well implemented, I think the problem is the func where it's call. Can you show us the func where it is call ?

Comment: Apple says that you have to dismiss UIAlertView when user presses the home button.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i figured it out why there was so much alerts, My code was correct, but i was calling [self.tableview viewdidload] and this opened another thread and this thread opened two more Threads......

Comment: @verklixt I know this is an old post, but could you explain what that means exactly, because I'm having the same problem with an alert made in one file randomly showing up several times elsewhere.

Comment: @Ryan, I wanted to refresh my Tableview with calling: [self.tableview viewdidload].
This was very bad, because it opened new Threads with 2^n.
That means I had very much Threads until the App crashed.
May you tell me exactly what happens, maybe some sourcecode will be helpful

Comment: @verklixt Ok well it's not causing my app to crash, but I have an alert that pops up in one function of my app, and then I dismiss it. Then, sometimes when I go to other functions of the app, that same alert that is defined in a different class randomly pops up when a view loads, often several of the same one. I can't figure out why, and unfortunately I can't force this to happen consistently and just have to wait for it to happen every so often, so debugging is impossible. If you have any ideas let me know, but I know it's tough to go off of such a vague description:)

Comment: Don't worry I have an idea, please search this in stack overflow I had found answers to it.
I only can vague remember, but i think you have to release it in applicationWillEnterForeground, its going into multitasking mode.
I have no references for that, sorry.
But you will find a solution here!
Hope you`ll get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear {
    [super viewWillDisappear];
    [myAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i figured it out why there was so much alerts, My code was correct, but i was calling [self.tableview  viewdidload] and this opened another thread and this thread opened two more Threads......